# Code Won't Compile With Android NDK

Tags: c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

Cocos2d-x is a C++ port of Cocos2d-for-iPhone. It has the advantage of cross-platform. I'm using Cocos2d-x to develop games for Android and iPhone.

Right now I'm compiling a set of Cocos2d-X code with both Android NDK and Xcode.

On Xcode the game compiles and runs well on the iPhone.

With Android NDK, the compile would fail. (I'm using the official Android r7c NDK).

Please help.

[image]

Edited: For those of you who're interested in the full implementation file. Here it is.

```
#include "GameOverScene.h"
#include "HelloWorldScene.h"

using namespace cocos2d;

bool GameOverScene::init() {
    if (CCScene::init()) {
        this->_layer = GameOverLayer::node();
        this->_layer->retain();
        this->addChild(_layer);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

GameOverScene::~GameOverScene () {
    if (_layer) {
        _layer->release();
        _layer = NULL;
    }
}

bool GameOverLayer::init () {
    if (CCLayerColor::initWithColor(ccc4f(255, 255, 255, 255))) {
        CCSize winSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
        this->_label = CCLabelTTF::labelWithString("", "Artial", 32);
        _label->retain();
        _label->setColor(ccc3(0, 0, 0));
        _label->setPosition(ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2));
        this->addChild(_label);

        this->runAction(CCSequence::actions(CCDelayTime::actionWithDuration(3), CCCallFunc::actionWithTarget(this, callfunc_selector(GameOverLayer::gameOverDone)), NULL));

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

void GameOverLayer::gameOverDone() {
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(HelloWorld::scene());
}

GameOverLayer::~GameOverLayer() {
    if (_label) {
        _label->release();
        _label = NULL;
    }
}
```

And the full header file

```
#ifndef S6_GameOverScene_h
#define S6_GameOverScene_h

#include "cocos2d.h"

class GameOverLayer : public cocos2d::CCLayerColor {

public:
    GameOverLayer():_label(NULL) {};
    virtual ~GameOverLayer();
    bool init();
    LAYER_NODE_FUNC(GameOverLayer);

    void gameOverDone();

    CC_SYNTHESIZE_READONLY(cocos2d::CCLabelTTF*, _label, Label);

};

class GameOverScene : public cocos2d::CCScene {

public:
    GameOverScene():_layer(NULL) {};
    ~GameOverScene();
    bool init();

    //SCENE_NODE_FUNC(GameOverScene);

    static GameOverScene* node()
    {
        GameOverScene *pRet = new GameOverScene();

        //Error: undefined reference to `GameOverScene::init()'
        if (pRet && pRet->init())
        {
            pRet->autorelease();
            return pRet;
        }
        else
        {
            //Error: undefined reference to `vtable for GameOverScene'
            delete pRet;

            pRet = NULL;
            return NULL;
        }
    }; 

    CC_SYNTHESIZE_READONLY(GameOverLayer*, _layer, Layer);
};


#endif
```

Comment: Didn't you just ask this a few minutes ago? Where's your implementation for those methods?

Comment: Try posting the compiler errors as well, not just that there was an error.

Comment: @Mat I just added the implementation file. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Kevin In the screenshot there're error descriptions. Here's a full one: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/game_shared/__/__/Classes/HelloWorldScene.o: In function `GameOverScene::node()':
/Users/my_account_name/Desktop/Projects/S6/S6/android/jni/../../Classes/GameOverScene.h:40: undefined reference to `GameOverScene::init()'

Comment: @diwup: I do not see errors in the screenshot and please no screenshots for displaying codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be problem with Android.mk file.. In that you need to add your GameOverScene.h file for compilation..

Answer (score 1):

> /Users/my_account_name/Desktop/Projects/S6/S6/android/jni/../../Classes/GameOver‌​Scene.h:40: undefined reference to GameOverScene::init()'

You have to link with `GameOverScene`'s object file.

Answer (score 1):

You might forget to add GameOverScene.cpp in Android.mk located at Classed folder.